# Где ошибка в клиенте WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf

Есть WCF который принимает файлы и сохраняет на сервере.
Код клиента:

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                #region Загрузка и перевод файла
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(@openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                int len = (int)fs.Length;
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, len);
                #region Формируем массив buffer в ручном режиме
                //string st = string.Empty;
                //for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                //{
                //    st += buffer[i].ToString() + ", ";
                //}
                //textBox1.Text = st;
                //byte[] buffer = { 37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 52, 10, 37, 226, 227, 207, 211, 10, 49, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 10, 60, 60, 10, 47, 84, 121 };
                #endregion
                fs.Close();
                #endregion
                client.Load("Тест", 15, "Тестовый_файл.rtf", 60, buffer); //Обращаемся к WCF
            }
```

Вопрос в следующем: почему WCF выкидывает исключение на превышение лимита ожидания - только когда buffer заполняется автоматически.
Если buffer заполнить в ручную то все ОК, где искать ошибку?
заполнение buffer в ручную (выдержка из массива в оригинале 56Кб, размер не имеет значения т.к. в ручном режиме были переданы файлы до 200Мб):

```
byte[] buffer = { 37, 80, 68, 70, 45, 49, 46, 52, 10, 37, 226, 227, 207, 211, 10, 49, 32, 48, 32, 111, 98, 106, 10, 60, 60, 10, 47, 84, 121 };
```

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="MetadataExchangeTcpBinding_IService1" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://192.168.2.8:10207/Service1" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="svc.IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://192.168.2.8:10208/Service1" binding="netTcpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="MetadataExchangeTcpBinding_IService1"
                contract="svc.IService1" name="MetadataExchangeTcpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

При тестировании WCF сервиса через WcfTestClient все проходит на Ура.
т.е. ошибка где то в клиенте, вопрос где?

В добавок закину код службы WCF:
IService1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFID
{
    // ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ. Команду "Переименовать" в меню "Рефакторинг" можно использовать для одновременного изменения имени интерфейса "IService1" в коде и файле конфигурации.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract(Name = "ListFiles")]
        string[] ListFiles(int idLetter);

        [OperationContract(Name = "Load")]
        void Load(string Unit, int idLetter, string name, int idAuthor, byte[] file);

        [OperationContract(Name = "UnLoad")]
        byte[] UnLoad(string Unit, int idFile);
    }
}
```

Service1:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WCFID
{
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        static string DirPatch = @"F:\Электронная приемная\Файлы";
        private DataTable Get(string req)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlConnectionStringBuilder mysqlSB = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            mysqlSB.Server = "192.168.2.8";
            mysqlSB.Port = порт;
            mysqlSB.Database = "БД";
            mysqlSB.UserID = "логин";
            mysqlSB.Password = "пароль";
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = mysqlSB.ConnectionString;
                MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand(req, con);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader dr = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (dr.HasRows)
                            dt.Load(dr);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }

        private void log(string text)
        {
            string path = "log.eprlog";
            if (File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path, true);
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + text);
                writer.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                // Создаем файл.
                File.Create(path);
                System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path, true);
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + text);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }



        /*Загрузка документа с номером если его нет то ошибка продумать класс с полями: документ, информационное сообщение*/
        public string[] ListFiles(int idLetter)
        {
            DataTable dt = Get("SELECT file_ep.idFile FROM file_ep WHERE file_ep.idLetter = '" + idLetter + "';");
            string[] res = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    res[i] = dt.Rows[i].Field<object>(dt.Columns[0].Caption).ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log(ex.ToString());
            }
            return res;
        }

        public void Load(string Unit, int idLetter, string name, int idAuthor, byte[] file)
        {
            try
            {
                //Загружаем файл на сервер
                string nameFile = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
                var path = DirPatch + @"\" + nameFile + "_" + name;
                FileStream fss = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                fss.Write(file, 0, file.Length);
                fss.Close();

                //пишем в бд инфу: ид письма, имя файла, автора, путь (автоматически)
                Get("INSERT INTO `file_ep` (`Unit`, `idLetter`, `name`, `path`, `idAuthor`) VALUES ('"+Unit+"', '" + idLetter.ToString() + "', '" + name + "', '" + path.Replace(@"\", "/") + "', '" + idAuthor.ToString() + "')");
                log("INSERT INTO `file_ep` (`Unit`, `idLetter`, `name`, `path`, `idAuthor`) VALUES ('" + Unit + "', '" + idLetter.ToString() + "', '" + name + "', '" + path.Replace(@"\", "/") + "', '" + idAuthor.ToString() + "')");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log(ex.ToString());
            }
        }


        public byte[] UnLoad(string Unit, int idFile)
        {
            Byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
            try
            {
                //Запрашиваем из БД путь к файлу
                DataTable dt = Get("SELECT file_ep.path FROM file_ep WHERE file_ep.idFile = '" + idFile.ToString() + "' and file_ep.Unit = '"+Unit+"';");
                string path = dt.Rows[0].Field<string>(dt.Columns[0].Caption).Replace("/", @"\");
                //Отдаем файл клиенту
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
                buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                int len = (int)fs.Length;
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, len);
                fs.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log(ex.ToString());
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Увеличьте тайматуты на отправку и прием сообщений (например, 10 минут):

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                />
        </basicHttpBinding>
```

---

**Однако, рекомендую вам использовать другой способ для передачи файлов в WCF.**

По умолчанию при обмене данными в WCF все сообщение буферизируется целиком, т.е. полностью считываются/формируются в памяти. Это происходит как при отправке, так и при получении сообщения. Очевидно, если вы попытаетесь отправить файл размером в несколько гигабайт (даже в несколько десятков мегабайт), то в памяти сообщение такого размера может просто не поместиться, плюс на формирование и чтение такого сообщения потребуется много времени.

Для больших объемов данных в WCF предназначена [потоковая передача](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742(v=vs.110).aspx). Данные из файла в этом случае будут передаваться не как массив байт, а как `Stream`. Это обеспечивает минимальное потребление памяти.

Однако, у этого режима есть ряд условий и ограничений.

Во-первых, контракт операции (в нашем случае `Load`) должен содержать не более одного параметра. Этот параметр должен быть либо непосредственно стримом (сериализуемым) с данными, либо контрактом сообщения. Первый вариант не подходит, поскольку у нас есть дополнительные параметры (`Unit`, `idLetter` и т.д.), поэтому придется их обернуть в дополнительный класс - контракт сообщения:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    // параметры придется передавать через дополнительный класс
    [OperationContract]
    void Load(LoadParameters parameters);
}

[MessageContract]
public class LoadParameters
{
    [MessageHeader]
    public string Unit;

    [MessageHeader]
    public int idLetter;

    [MessageHeader]
    public string name;

    [MessageHeader]
    public int idAuthor;

    // Необходимо, чтобы в теле сообщения передавались данные из стрима,
    // а все остальные данные - через заголовки
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public Stream file;
}
```

В реализации контракта копируйте `parameters.file`:

```
public void Load(LoadParameters parameters)
{
    // ...

    using (var os = File.OpenWrite(fileName)) {
        parameters.file.CopyTo(os);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Далее, в конфигурации (как сервера, так и клиента) для привязок необходимо включить режим передачи `Streamed`:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="streamedHttpBinding"
             transferMode="Streamed"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="4294967296"
             maxBufferSize="65536"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<client>
  <endpoint
    address="http://192.168.2.8:10207/Service1"
    binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="streamedHttpBinding" <!-- так же для серверной части -->
    contract="svc.IService1" />
</client>
```

Параметр `maxReceivedMessageSize` задает максимальный размер *всего* сообщения - т.е. размер файла + длина дополнительных аргументов + дополнительный оверхэд из-за сериализации.

Параметр `maxBufferSize` определяет размер буфера под чтение сообщения. В буферизированном (стандартном) режиме это значение не учитывается - оно автоматически выставляется равным `maxReceivedMessageSize` (т.е. все сообщение будет считано в память целиком). В потоковом режиме размер буфера уже учитывается, сообщение будет считываться в память порциями такого размера.

Параметры `receiveTimeout`, `sendTimeout` тоже укажем, если потребуется сохранить очень большой файл.

На стороне клиенте не считывайте файл в массив, а просто передавайте стрим в параметрах:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open)) {
    var param = new LoadParameters()
    {
        Unit = ...,
        idAuthor = ...,
        idLetter = ...,
        name = ...,
        file = fs,
    };
    client.Load(param);
}
```

Comment: действительно проблема была в задержке, поправил все работает. Так как недавно начал работать с WCF про потоковую передачу информации было интересно узнать, буду использовать...
Спасибо!

Comment: Большая просьба помочь реализовать данную функцию (Load) через потоковую передачу (Понимаю, что все расписано, но что то не выходит у меня) опиши подробно код и конфиг клиента и код и конфиг сервиса буду очень признателен.